# How to handle post json using net core function app?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

Using **.net core** (azure) **function app** I want to handle a **POST** /command request that contains a json object in the body of the request.
What is the best approach for writing these type of handlers?

My current solution is to use an HttpTrigger that reads json from the body as a stream using a streamreader.

```
[FunctionName("command")]
    public async Task<IActionAsynResult> HandleCommand(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "POST", Route = "command")]
        HttpRequest request,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            var requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var command = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Command>(requestBody);
        }

        return new OkObjectResult(new List<MyType>());
    }
```

Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need custom handling of the JSON serialization, you can directly have the `Command` object passed into your Function, instead of `HttpRequest`.

```
[FunctionName("command")]
public async Task<IActionAsynResult> HandleCommand(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "POST", Route = "command")]
    Command command, ILogger logger)
{
    return new OkObjectResult(new List<MyType>());
}
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#payload)